# I have Multiple modal pop on my page , when i click submit, i am able to get the form values of the first modal pop but not others

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popup, click, dom-events

I have created multiple optional modal pop ups. Each pop up has a form where i get user input .When i click the first submit button, i get the values, but when the user clicks on the search more details button to fill in a second or a third pop up when he clicks submit button, the forms suddenly dissappers as if it submits.

I am using Classes, i am relatively new to java script but i am feeling quite frustrated after trying this for several days now.

Someone please help.

The code is a available here
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sun-l4qo9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Your link takes hours to load, your code should be here

Answer (score 1):

You should just listen for the `submit` event (check out the [Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) section). 
There's no `submit-two` or `submit-three` event in js.

So try getting rid of submit parameter in your `ModalPopUp` constructor and change the following line:

```
.addEventListener(this.submit, this.validate)
```

to:

```
.addEventListener('submit', this.validate)
```

Comment: thanks Mike this works with modal three now let me check what is wrong with modal two.